# How store login credentials in Redux store?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm figuring out the data-flow, and writing action oriented code to deal with Redux.

This is the flow: 
I reach SplashScreen and check if accessToken exists. If no, I send the user to LoginScreen. Else, I take him to the HomeScreen.

The flow is rather simple but I'm not able to wrap my head around how to store the token, expire the token or just check if user is logged in. So, technically, when a user logs in, the state(access token) should change. I'm not asking for code, just some pseudo-code and a little explanation will help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user the redux store to save token or any user credentials you will need to ensure the state is saved on localStorage, and for that you can use a redux middleware [like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-storage) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist), or you can use middle-ware of your own :

```
export default store => next => action => {
  let result = next(action)
  localStorage.state = JSON.stringify(store.getState())
  return result
}
```

I don't know if you are using react router, If you are, take a look at this example: [authenticator](https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example#how-it-works) I think it's really the best way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

In my app I used [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain). When a user logs in, I store the accessToken in the redux store. From there, any time I'm making a request, I just get the token from the store, ensure that it's valid, and make the request.